# Set up activex combobox in excel always triggers dirty flag

Tags: excel, vba, combobox

I have an activex combobox that is filled as the sheet opens.  However, despite my best efforts it always triggers the dirty flag and asks the user to save even if no changes have been made.  Here is the relevant code:

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    Application.EnableEvents = False ' => disable events
    'set up dropdown menu on topics tab
    mbEvents = False
    With Sheets("Do Now Topic")
    'Set up combobox1
        With .ComboBox1
            .Clear
            .List = getUniqueArray(Sheets("Questions").Range("D2:D" & LastRow.Row))
            .Text = Sheets("Questions").Cells(Sheets("Questions").Range("A2:A" & LastRow.Row).Find(What:=Sheets("Do Now Topic").Cells(3, 13), LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchDirection:=xlNext, matchCase:=False).Row, 4)
        End With
    End With
    mbEvents = True
    Application.EnableEvents = True ' => enable events
    ActiveWorkbook.Saved = True
End Sub
```

Here is the event handler for the combobox

```
Dim RecalculateAll As Boolean

'Combobox change event
Private Sub ComboBox1_Change()
    If Not mbEvents Then
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    Sheets("Do Now Topic").Cells(3, 13) = Sheets("Questions").Cells(Sheets("Questions").Range("D2:D" & LastRow.Row).Find(What:=ComboBox1.Value, LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchDirection:=xlNext, matchCase:=False).Row, 1)
    Sheets("Do Now Topic").Cells(3, 16) = Sheets("Questions").Cells(Sheets("Questions").Range("D2:D" & LastRow.Row).Find(What:=ComboBox1.Value, LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, matchCase:=False).Row, 1)
    
    RecalculateAll = True
    Sheets("Data").Calculate
    Sheets("Do Now Topic").Calculate
    RecalculateAll = False
    
End Sub
```

I am not sure why it is setting the dirty flag when the worksheet opens.  It is definitely to do with the combobox though.

Comment: Well, you _have_ changed the combo box, even if you just reload the same data that was already there, so it's not surprising the book is marked dirty. Have you tried testing if the data has changed  before loading it to the combo box?

Comment: but at the end of the open workbook sub I include "ActiveWorkbook.Saved = True".  Why does this not mark it as no longer dirty?